# Lodash: What's the opposite of `_uniq()`?

Tags: lodash

The `_.uniq()` in lodash removes duplicates from an array:

```
var tst = [
 { "topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName1":"w" },
 { "topicId":2,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"b","subTopicName2":"x" },
 { "topicId":3,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"c","subTopicName3":"y" },
 { "topicId":1,"subTopicId":4,"topicName":"c","subTopicName4":"z" }]

var t = _.uniq(tst, 'topicName')
```

This returns:

```
[ {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName1":"w" }, 
  { topicId: 2, subTopicId: 2, topicName: 'b', subTopicName2: 'x' },
  { topicId: 3, subTopicId: 3, topicName: 'c', subTopicName3: 'y' } ]
```

What's the opposite of this? It should only return a single object for each duplicate object:

```
[ { topicId: 3, subTopicId: 3, topicName: 'c', subTopicName3: 'y' } ]
```

Comment: There isn't anything for this as it isn't a common usecase, but you could filter your array, reject anything without duplicates, and then take the first from that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in method, here's something that should do the job:

```
function dupesOnly(arr, field) {
    var seen = {},
        ret = [];

    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = item[field],
            val = seen[key];

        if (!val) {
            seen[key] = val = {
                initial: item,
                count: 0
            }
        }

        if (val.count === 1) {
            ret.push(val.initial);
        }
        ++val.count;
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: OP wanted a lodash solution, so why not use lodash?

Comment: So that you could comment "why not use lodash". It worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit duplicate function in lodash but you could use some combinations of lodash functions

```
var dupesOnlyByObjectKeyInCollection = function(collection, objectKey) {
    const countByName = _.countBy(collection, objectKey);
    const duplicates = _.filter(collection, (object) => countByName[object[objectKey]] > 1);
    return _.uniqBy(duplicates, (x,y) => x[objectKey])
}
```